# Sorting array values (vcard parameters) to variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vcf-vcard

I have the following question:

**(Everything what follows, needs to be solved in JS)**

I have an array, containing the arguments of a vcard, and I have some variables defined. What I want to reach is, bringing the parameters or the arguments of the array into the Variables. So I have an array that looks e.G like this:

```
array[0] --> BEGIN:VCARD  
array[1] --> VERSION: 3.0  
array[2] --> FN: John Doe  
array[3] --> url: www.google.de  
array[4] --> title: ceo
```

And so on. The problem it now, that there are two (or more Versions and kinds) what the attributs can look like, so eg. the work-telephone can look either like: `TEL;WORK;VOICE` or `TEL;WORK`; or `TEL`, or `TEL;TYPE=voice,work` or `TEL; TYPE=voice,work,pref`, or `TEL TYPE=work, CHARSET=UTF-8` or some more possibilities. 
The other problem is, that (depending on the vcard information) the arguments are sorted in another way, so sometimes url is at the end, sometimes in the middle, sometimes on beginning, same with the other ones.

The other thing I have now are the variables, defined with:
`var Accname, Street, City, PostCode, Country, FirstName, LastName, JobTitle, Mail, PhoneNumber;`

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

The only thing that came in my mind was asking for every element in the array if it exists (because I don't know how many elements are in there) and then asking having as many for-loops from 0 - length of array as elements in the array and checking in every for-loop `if(array[2]==FN){//save the value to a variable}`, same with the other arguments. But the first problem here is that I would have lots of confusing unclearly code and the other problem is: I need just the value in the variables and sometimes I even have to split them, so I e.g have the variables FirstName and LastName but what I have saved in the array is `FN: John Doe`, what I need is setting FirstName to John, and LastName to Doe.

Does anybody know a compact, clear and maintainable solution to do so?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

What I tried now (solution of Mathieu) is the following:

```
var aliases =
            {
              '/FN/i':'name',
              '/TITLE/i':'jobtitle',
              '/ORG/i':'accname',
              '/EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET/i':'mail',
              '/EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET/i':'mail',
              '/EMAIL;INTERNET/i':'mail',
              '/EMAIL/i':'mail',
              '/TEL;WORK;VOICE/i':'phone',
              '/TEL;TYPE=voice,work,pref/i':'phone',
              '/TEL;TYPE=voice,work/i':'phone',
              '/TEL;WORK/i':'phone',
              '/TEL:TYPE=work/i':'phone',
              '/TEL;CELL/i':'mobile',
              '/TEL;TYPE=voice,cell,pref/i':'mobile',
              '/TEL;TYPE=voice,cell/i':'mobile',
              '/TEL;TYPE=cell/i':'mobile',
              '/ADDR/i':'address'
            };

            var idx;
            var out={}, i, ci = fields.length;
            for(i=0;i<ci;i++) // 1
                for(idx in aliases) // 2
                    if(aliases.hasOwnProperty(idx)) // 3
                        if(fields[i].search(eval(idx)) >= 0) // 4
                             out[aliases[idx]] = fields[i].substring(fields[i].indexOf(':')+1); // 5

            //document.write(JSON.stringify(out));

            alert(out['accname']);
```

But what I get in the alert is the complete content of the qr code...
Any Ideas why?

**EDIT2:**
Working now, had a little mistake getting my array back. Thank you.

Comment: It'll be hard to say without having the input... (variable `fields`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick i think.

```
<script>
var vcard = ['BEGIN:VCARD','VERSION: 3.0','FN: John Doe','url: www.google.de', 'TEL TYPE=work, CHARSET=UTF-8: 0123466','title: ceo' ];

// Define here filters for the fields you want
var aliases = 
{
  '/tel/i':'Tel',
  '/work/i':'Tel',
  '/FN/i':'Name',
};

var out={}, i, ci = vcard.length;
for(i=0;i<ci;i++) // 1
  for(idx in aliases) // 2
    if(aliases.hasOwnProperty(idx)) // 3
      if(vcard[i].search(eval(idx)) >= 0) // 4
        out[aliases[idx]] = vcard[i].substring(vcard[i].indexOf(':')+1); // 5

document.write(JSON.stringify(out));

</script>
```

Comment: Could you shortly eplain me 1. how the thing in the for loops work) and 2. what exactly I have to define in aliases, didn't get this to be honest. So are the things behind the : the names of the variables? And why you need the /i ?

Comment: Since `aliases` is a plain object, you don't need (3).

Comment: 1. Loop through the vcard array
2+3: Loop though the "aliases" object.
4. Lookup the mask (from aliases) in the vcard array element.
5. Put the vcard array element in our "out" object. (beginning at ":")

;;; the /i means the search will be case Insensitive.

Comment: You can copy/past in an html file and execute step by step to understand precisely... And thank you Pavlo.

Comment: This can help you to undersand the /seek/i thing: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Comment: Okay, I understood this now, but still didn't get my 2. question. What do I have to define in the aliases? The things before the ":" seem to be the possible "names" for the attributes, so e.g fn, url, title, or even TEL;WORK;VOICE, the things behind the ":" are the variables the content after the ":" will be saved in, am I right? If yes, how can I use them after this procedure? So how do I have to address them?

Comment: Yes: things before the ":" are search patterns for the attributes, and after the semicolon, the name in which it'll be stored.
After the loops you can access the variable through the "out" object. like alert(out['Tel']); or alert(out.Tel); (same thing)

Comment: My solution doesnt cover the splitting from first name & last name. But it should not be a problem after that the fields are extracted. (just break the out.Name at the first space or something like this.).